# Apache Ignite.NET Error loading ignite.jni.dll

Tags: .net, iis, ignite

So I have Apache Ignite.NET all configured. And I got it working with a JDK installed etc..

I now have an interesting problem. I deployed my application on a server and I keep getting this error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedUtils' threw an exception. ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Failed to load ignite.jni.dll from C:\Windows\TEMP\Ignite_rqjux5at.wm5\ignite.jni.dll: [DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. Make sure that Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package is installed (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632).]
```

I do have Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package installed on that server and a JRE 1.8

I wonder if anyone has seen this before.

I checked the documentation here: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/v2.0/docs/troubleshooting

And it says make sure Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package is installed. I wonder is 2013 too new for it? Or is there some other issue that I might not be realizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think that you should install the exact MSVC package version since those aren't forward or backward compatible usually.

Second, it's kind of weird that your .dll path includes `\\Windows\\TEMP\\`. Properly deployed applications don't usually do that.

Third, there exist an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5730 but it doesn't strike immediately as the one you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of the c++ redistributable did not work for me, so can be a bit of a rabbit hole. In the end, I installed [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632)